# Excel Screen Flickers a lot despite Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Tags: excel, vba

I am using excel VBA to create a new sheet then copy data from another sheet to this new sheet I created. Then I will format the new sheet by deleting some columns and text wrapping. It does the job alright However it is not efficient: The screen flickers so much despite  using  Application.DisplayAlerts = False, Application.EnableEvents = False.
Any help?

```
Sub ProcessPostingData()
    Dim MyDateTime As String
    Dim szToday As String
    Dim szTime As String
    Dim TD, TM As String
    Dim AfterFilterFinalRow As Long
    Dim lLastRow3nd As Long


    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets("szTempNow").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Sheets.Add().Name = "szTempNow"

    Worksheets("DATA_PROCESSING").Select

        lLastRow3nd = Cells(1, 6).EntireColumn.Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    'We sort,create sheet with DateTime stamp,copy data to new sheet and format

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA_PROCESSING").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lLastRow3nd, 10)).Sort _
    Key1:=Range("A1"), Header:=xlYes


    With Worksheets("DATA_PROCESSING")
            AfterFilterFinalRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Sheets("DATA_PROCESSING").Range("A1:J1").Copy Destination:=Sheets("szTempNow").Range("A1")
    Sheets("szTempNow").Range("A2:J" & AfterFilterFinalRow).Value = Sheets("DATA_PROCESSING").Range("A2:J" & AfterFilterFinalRow).Value

    Sheets("DATA_PROCESSING").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(AfterFilterFinalRow, 10)).EntireRow.Delete

    'Removing columns not needed and formating
    Sheets("szTempNow").Select

      'With Sheets("szTempNow")
      .Columns("G:G").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
      .Columns("D:E").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    End With

       'With Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(AfterFilterFinalRow, 10))

           '.HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
           '.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
           '.WrapText = True
           '.ReadingOrder = xlContext
        'End With

       'Range("E2:E" & AfterFilterFinalRow).Columns("E:E").ColumnWidth = 70

    'Rename Sheet with Todays date and Time

    szTime = Format(Time, "h-mm AM/PM")
    szToday = Format(Now(), "dd-mmm-yyyy")
        TD = "D"
        TM = "T"

     MyDateTime = TD & szToday & TD & "_" & TM & szTime & TM

      ActiveSheet.Name = MyDateTime

      Range("K1").Value = ActiveSheet.Name

      Range("K1").Font.Bold = True
        With Range("K1")
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            .ReadingOrder = xlContext
      End With

      Application.EnableEvents = False
      Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

That's the one that helps stop screen flickering, and can also speed up processing. `Application.DisplayAlerts` suppresses dialogs along the lines of "This Workbook is Unsaved."